# Not able to connect with remote mysql from code but it works from terminal on the same machine

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using this code to connect to mysql hosted on a remote server:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(ip:3306)/gotest") //also tried without tcp
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But it return me this error message:

**Error 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'ip' to database 'gotest'
exit status 1**

Privileges are set correctly. I'm able to connect using mysql command from terminal on the same machine where i run the code.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are replacing the `ip` with actual host name right?

Comment: Server ip is the actual hostname

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct if you fill variables correctly.

for make sure about it, I changed your code to this:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", user, pass, ip, port, dbname))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

please use it and fill variables.